# MYSQL Multi Table Delete

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables setup like this:

```
Items:
   id (int)
   name (varchar)
   category (int)
   last_update (timestamp)

Categories
   id (int)
   name (varchar)
   tree_id (int)
```

I want to delete all the records from `Items`, who's `last_update` is NOT today, and who's corresponding `categories.tree_id` is equal to 1.  However, I don't want to delete anything from the `Categories` table, just the `Items` table.  I tried this:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM items USING categories, items
    WHERE items.category = categories.id
    AND categories.tree_id = 1
    AND items.last_update != '".date('Y-m-d')."'";
```

However this just seems to delete EVERY record who's `tree_id` is 1.  It should keep items with a `tree_id` of 1, as long as their `last_update` field is `today`

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You say that last_update contains time-stamps - I assume UNIX time-stamp. You can never find a record with the same time-stamp as when the stamp was executed and you can not compare a time-stamp with formatted date, they'll never correspond. So you need to store the data in last_update column in a date(Y-m-d) format so that compare those which are not equal.

Comment: Please note that a MySQL timestamp field IS NOT the same as a UNIX timestamp.  The only issue you have right now is in comparing a timestamp field (which contains both date and time components) with only a date value.  This propose solution of usiong a date field (rather than timestamp or datetime field), would not allow you to know the H:m:s time component of last_update.

Answer (score 1):

If last_update is a timestamp field,and you are only passing in a date (with no time component) in your where clause, you are, in essence, actually doing this (if passing in 2012-10-24 for example):

```
AND items.last_update != 2012-10-24 00:00:00
```

This means every row without that exact second value in the timestamp would be deleted.  You are much better doing something like

```
AND items.last_update NOT LIKE '".date('Y-m-d')."%'";
```

Of course you want to make sure you have an index on last_update.

Or if you don't care about index performance on last_update field (i.e. you are just doing this as a one off query and don't want to index this field), you could do this, which may make more logical sense to some

```
AND DATE(items.last_update) <> '".date('Y-m-d')."'"
```

The bottom line is that you need to only be comparing the date component of the last_updated field in some manner.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a subquery

```
DELETE FROM items USING categories, items
    WHERE items.category = categories.id
    AND items.last_update != '".date('Y-m-d')."'"
    AND items.id in 
    (
      SELECT id from items inner join categories on item.category = categories.id
    )
```